# Angular 7 how to execute script tag from dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, grapesjs

I'm integrating `GrapesJS` with `Lory slider` into angular 7, and I need to load inline scripts that the editor generates to give functionality to the slider.

I need to load dynamically components inside the HTML that's why I use "**dynamic-html**" component.

I've tried to reload the scripts with directives but nothing works, it seems that Angular can't find the element.

### **TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-paginas',
  styleUrls: ['./paginas.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
  template : `<dynamic-html [content]="pagina.html"></dynamic-html>`
})
```

### Script that editor returns inside "**pagina.html**"

```
<script>var items = document.querySelectorAll('#ixuhz');        for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {          (function(){var e=this,t="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lory.js/2.3.4/lory.min.js",l=["0","false"],s="";s="true"==s?1:parseInt(s,10);var a={slidesToScroll:parseInt("1",10),enableMouseEvents:l.indexOf("")>=0?0:1,infinite:!isNaN(s)&&s,rewind:!(l.indexOf("")>=0),slideSpeed:parseInt("300",10),rewindSpeed:parseInt("600",10),snapBackSpeed:parseInt("200",10),ease:"ease",classNameFrame:"gjs-lory-frame",classNameSlideContainer:"gjs-lory-slides",classNamePrevCtrl:"gjs-lory-prev",classNameNextCtrl:"gjs-lory-next"},r=function(){window.sliderLory=lory(e,a)};if("undefined"==typeof lory){var n=document.createElement("script");n.src=t,n.onload=r,document.head.appendChild(n)}else r()}.bind(items[i]))();        }</script>
```

### Expecting get some result but not find anything

[image: Slider Without Script Loading]

Trying to get the element with Jquery or JS

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  console.log($("#ixuhz"));
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused: would you like to use 'templateUrl' or 'template'?

Comment: @BaruchG. I like to use 'template' for load the content

Comment: "pagina.html"  is the HTML file of the </ dynamic-html> component ?

Comment: @BaruchG. Yes “pagina.html” is an string that contains the HTML of the slider and the “<script>” code

Answer (score 0):

you can use [import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) to sanitaze dynamic data added into template.

But i think need to use it like this 
`<div [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content)"></div>`

Here is [link to document](https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis)

Comment: If i use your answer i get the following error: ERROR Error: Required a safe HTML, got a Script (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)